# Android Studio: Attempt to setOnClickListener on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to cause a new activity to start when a user clicks the logout button. However whenever I click on the button the app crashes and gives the calling setOnClickListener on a null object reference. The Java code is below

```
package hanyang.hyu_se;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button bNewGroup, bLogout;
EditText etSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    bNewGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNewGroup);
    bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
    etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

    bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    bNewGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLogout:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, login.class));

            break;
        case R.id.bNewGroup:

            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

At first my problem was that when I had manually typed in Button it didn't called the widget button but after addressing that issue I am now stuck on this null object reference.

I have checked my XML and the important part is...

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:id="@+id/bLogout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Is this error occurring because the main activity is unable to locate the "bLogout" id? I have checked the syntax numerous times and I don't think that is the cause of the problem.

**EDIT**: Here is the error output. Sorry about the formatting... I tried to put it in a code section but it wouldn't let me add spaces to the front of the text for some reason...

> --------- beginning of crash 06-03 14:44:55.744 2400-2400/hanyang.hyu_se E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                 Process: hanyang.hyu_se, PID: 2400
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{hanyang.hyu_se/hanyang.hyu_se.login}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>       at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                     at hanyang.hyu_se.login.onCreate(login.java:31)
>                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Can you please paste the log output for the crash?

Comment: Also, where is the button R.id.bNewGroup? I don't see it in your XML.

Comment: I didn't include the bNewGroup in the XML as I didn't think it was important or relevant for this question but I can post it.

Comment: I asked about it because you do bNewGroup.setOnClickListener() and if R.id..bNewGroup was not found then bNewGroup would be NULL leading to such an exception.

Comment: try to clean your project

Comment: Set some breakpoints at ´bLogout = (Button)getViewById(R.id.bLogout)´ and ´switch(v.getId())´, and reprot back where it throws the exception, and maybe find out if your bLogout actually gets assigned (although it should; can't see why not).